# What is the best approach to embed a hosted React application in to another non React site?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have an entire React application that I am hosting on AWS. I want to embed this application in to another non React site. Currently I have it iframed in and it works fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://testlink.cloudfront.net"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have seen examples in the React docs around implementing individual components without iframes but nothing around entire hosted applications.

Idealy I will be able to do something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<body>
    <div="app"></div>
    <div="app2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the best approach to do this or am I best to just deal with iframes?

Answer (score 2):

I had to integrate multiple react apps into a cake php framework.

Place the final bundle in webroot of the hosted site e.g under /react.
Then just include the final bundled script tag in the html.
You will have to handle the routing to the app on the hosted site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8">
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="ReactAppDiv"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/react/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not quite sure this is what I'm after. I'm hoping to keep the 2 projects seperate so I don't want to include bundled files in to the non React site if possible.

Comment: Then you are looking at using <iframe> ? ... not really possible.